# Как встроить переменную Pug в Vue структуру?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pug

Есть шаблон на pug и vuejs

```
#masthead(v-for="item in dataTitles[1].id" :class="dataTitles[0].pageClass" :data-title="dataTitles[0].dataName")
   .content
       h1.pageTitle {{ dataTitles[0].dataName }}
```

Здесь [0, 1, ...] для **dataTitles** генерируется при помощи vue.js

Но, это структура **общего шаблона, а не страницы**. И я бы хотел, чтобы для нужной мне страницы выводилось нужное число.

Тут начинаются сложности.

Для выполнения задачи, я думаю создать *pug* переменную *- var dataNum = ['0','1']*, которая встраивались бы в значения dataTitles вместо [0], [1] и т.д.. И на нужной странице я бы просто менял значение этой переменной, например, **- dataNum = ['0','4']**. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать. Пытался по всякому, не выходит... Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Что такое `Pug` переменная? Прокомментируйте код.

Comment: - var имя_переменной = 'ее значение'

Comment: Такими комментариями не ждите помощи. И код оформите человекочитаемый  вид.

Comment: а что с ним не так? это фрагмент pug. Или вам перевести в html?

Comment: Вот это что такое: `#masthead(v-for="item in dataTitles[1].id" :class="dataTitles[0].pageClass" :data-title="dataTitles[0].dataName")`?

Comment: `Pug` — это же не просто переменная, раз вы её в заголовок вопроса вынесли.

Comment: перевожу в html
`<div id="masthead" v-for="item in dataTitles[1].id" :class="dataTitles[0].pageClass" :data-title="dataTitles[0].dataName">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 class="pageTitle">{{ dataTitles[0].dataName }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>` - это шаблон

`- var dataNum = ['0','1']` - это переменная